# Drag a shape from right to left in java swing

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, paint, drag

Hi I'm working now on a paint shapes program which you can select the shape then drag it to make a circle for example with the size you want .
However I face one problem which is that I just can drag from left to right not from right to left .

**see picture**
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qgBZD.png)

and this my panel draw
I think the problem is in **mouseDragged**

```
class DrawPanel extends JPanel {

    MouseMotionListener m2 = new MouseMotionListener() {

        @Override
        public void mouseMoved(MouseEvent e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        @Override
        public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent e) {

            Point newPoint = new Point(e.getX(), e.getY());

            if (shape == "1") {

                image = cloneImage(originalImage);
                int width = newPoint.x - oldPoint.x;
                int hieght = newPoint.y - oldPoint.y;

                drawCir(oldPoint.x, oldPoint.y, width, width);

                repaint();
            }

            else if (shape == "2") {
                image = cloneImage(originalImage);
                int width = newPoint.x - oldPoint.x;
                int hieght = newPoint.y - oldPoint.y;

                drawOval(oldPoint.x, oldPoint.y, width, hieght);
            }

            else if (shape == "3") {
                image = cloneImage(originalImage);
                int width = newPoint.x - oldPoint.x;
                int hieght = newPoint.y - oldPoint.y;

                drawRec(oldPoint.x, oldPoint.y, width, hieght);
            }

            else if (shape == "4") {
                image = cloneImage(originalImage);
                int width = newPoint.x - oldPoint.x;
                int hieght = newPoint.y - oldPoint.y;

                drawSqu(oldPoint.x, oldPoint.y, width, width);
            }


            else if (shape == "5") {
                image = cloneImage(originalImage);


                drawLine(oldPoint.x, oldPoint.y, newPoint.x, newPoint.y);
            }

        }
    };
    {

        this.addMouseMotionListener(m2);
    }

    MouseListener m1 = new MouseListener() {

        @Override
        public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        @Override
        public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {

            oldPoint = new Point(e.getX(), e.getY());

            originalImage = cloneImage(image);

        }

        @Override
        public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        @Override
        public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        @Override
        public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }
    };
    {

        this.addMouseListener(m1);
    }

    public DrawPanel() {

        setBackground(Color.white);

    }

    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);

        Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;

        if (image == null) {
            image = new BufferedImage(super.getWidth(), super.getHeight(), BufferedImage.TYPE_4BYTE_ABGR_PRE);
        }

        g2d.drawImage(image, 0, 0, null);

    }

    public void drawCir(int x, int y, int w, int h) {

        Graphics2D g = image.createGraphics();

        g.setColor(Color.black);

        if (drawSetting.getColor().equals("Black")) {
            g.setColor(Color.black);

        }

        else if (drawSetting.getColor().equals("Blue")) {
            g.setColor(Color.BLUE);

        }

        else if (drawSetting.getColor().equals("Red")) {
            g.setColor(Color.RED);

        }

        else if (drawSetting.getColor().equals("Green")) {
            g.setColor(Color.GREEN);

        }

        if (drawSetting.getFilled() == false) {
            g.drawOval(x, y, w, w);
        } else {
            g.fillOval(x, y, w, w);
        }

        repaint();
    }

    public void drawOval(int x, int y, int w, int h) {

        Graphics2D g = image.createGraphics();

        g.setColor(Color.black);

        if (drawSetting.getColor().equals("Black")) {
            g.setColor(Color.black);

        }

        else if (drawSetting.getColor().equals("Blue")) {
            g.setColor(Color.BLUE);

        }

        else if (drawSetting.getColor().equals("Red")) {
            g.setColor(Color.RED);

        }

        else if (drawSetting.getColor().equals("Green")) {
            g.setColor(Color.GREEN);

        }

        if (drawSetting.getFilled() == false) {
            g.drawOval(x, y, w, h);
        } else {
            g.fillOval(x, y, w, h);
        }

        repaint();
    }

    public void drawRec(int x, int y, int w, int h) {

        Graphics2D g = image.createGraphics();
        if (drawSetting.getColor().equals("Black")) {
            g.setColor(Color.black);

        }

        else if (drawSetting.getColor().equals("Blue")) {
            g.setColor(Color.BLUE);

        }

        else if (drawSetting.getColor().equals("Red")) {
            g.setColor(Color.RED);

        }

        else if (drawSetting.getColor().equals("Green")) {
            g.setColor(Color.GREEN);

        }

        if (drawSetting.getFilled() == false) {
            g.drawRect(x, y, w, h);
        } else {
            g.fillRect(x, y, w, h);
        }

        repaint();
    }

    public void drawSqu(int x, int y, int w, int h) {

        Graphics2D g = image.createGraphics();
        if (drawSetting.getColor().equals("Black")) {
            g.setColor(Color.black);

        }

        else if (drawSetting.getColor().equals("Blue")) {
            g.setColor(Color.BLUE);

        }

        else if (drawSetting.getColor().equals("Red")) {
            g.setColor(Color.RED);

        }

        else if (drawSetting.getColor().equals("Green")) {
            g.setColor(Color.GREEN);

        }

        if (drawSetting.getFilled() == false) {
            g.drawRect(x, y, w, w);
        } else {
            g.fillRect(x, y, w, w);
        }

        repaint();
    }

    public void drawLine(int x1, int y1, int x2, int y2) {

        Graphics2D g = image.createGraphics();
        if (drawSetting.getColor().equals("Black")) {
            g.setColor(Color.black);

        }

        else if (drawSetting.getColor().equals("Blue")) {
            g.setColor(Color.BLUE);

        }

        else if (drawSetting.getColor().equals("Red")) {
            g.setColor(Color.RED);

        }

        else if (drawSetting.getColor().equals("Green")) {
            g.setColor(Color.GREEN);

        }

        if (drawSetting.getFilled() == false) {
            g.drawLine(x1, y1, x2, y2);
        } else {
            g.drawLine(x1, y1, x2, y2);
        }

        repaint();
    }

    public void setShape(String s) {
        shape = s;
    }

    private BufferedImage cloneImage(BufferedImage image2) {

        if (image2 == null) {
            return null;
        }

        ColorModel cm = image2.getColorModel();
        boolean isAplpha = cm.isAlphaPremultiplied();
        WritableRaster raster = image2.copyData(null);

        return new BufferedImage(cm, raster, isAplpha, null);

    }

}
```

Comment: When you drag right-to-left, your width becomes negative (similar dragging up will cause height to be negative).  You need to recognize that when you drag to the left of your starting point, you need to update the x coordinate and compute a positive width, instead of trying to keep the starting point constant with a negative width, which doesn’t work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot use negative width and height values with those drawing functions.

Instead, you must detect a negative width, and adjust the starting coordinate to keep the width non-negative.

```
public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent e) {

    Point newPoint = new Point(e.getX(), e.getY());
    int xStart = oldPoint.x;
    int yStart = oldPointy;
    int width = newPoint.x - xStart;
    int height = newPoint.y - yStart;

    if (width < 0) {
        width = -width;
        xStart -= width;
    }
    if (height < 0) {
        height = -height;
        yStart -= height;
    }

    if (shape.equals("1")) {
        image = cloneImage(originalImage);
        drawCir(xStart, yStart, width, height);
        repaint();
    }
    ...etc...
```