# Using Graphics2D, when I drag the shapes, I want to move the shapes

Tags: java, graphics, mouseevent, graphics2d, affinetransform

When I drag the shapes that I drew, I want to move. 
but I do not know how to do it. 
I have tried the make move method in GPanel but could not make it. 
knowledge.

I have been working on this for almost 1 week and tried all the solutions that I could think of.

This is my first time posting a code question on stack overflow.

I do really want to learn.
. And love you all.

I hope one day I could be a savior for code newbies

Have to use affine transform

---

**this is drawing page**

```
package frame;

import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.Point;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.awt.event.MouseListener;
import java.awt.event.MouseMotionListener;
import java.awt.event.MouseWheelEvent;
import java.awt.event.MouseWheelListener;
import java.util.Vector;

import javax.swing.JPanel;

import main.GConstants.EAnchorLocation;
import main.GConstants.EDrawingStyle;
import shapeTool.GShapeTool;

public class GPanel extends JPanel {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

private GShapeTool shapeTool;
private GShapeTool selectedShape;
private Vector<GShapeTool> shapes;

public GPanel() {
    this.setBackground(Color.WHITE);

    this.shapes = new Vector<GShapeTool>();

    MouseHandler mouseHandler = new MouseHandler();
    this.addMouseListener(mouseHandler);
    this.addMouseMotionListener(mouseHandler);
    this.addMouseWheelListener(mouseHandler);
}

public void initialize() {}

public Vector<GShapeTool> getShapes() {
    return this.shapes;
}

public void setShapes(Vector<GShapeTool> shapes){
    this.shapes = shapes;
    this.updateUI();
}


public void paint(Graphics graphics) {
    super.paint(graphics);
    for(GShapeTool shape: this.shapes) {
        shape.draw((Graphics2D)graphics);
    }
}

public void setShapeTool(GShapeTool shapeTool) {
    this.shapeTool = shapeTool;
}

private boolean onShape(int x, int y) {
    boolean shapeCheck = false;
    for(GShapeTool shapeTool: this.shapes) {
        if(shapeTool.contains(x, y)) {
            this.selectedShape = shapeTool;
            shapeCheck = true;
        } else {
            shapeTool.setSelected(false, (Graphics2D)getGraphics());
        }
    }
    if(shapeCheck) {
        this.selectedShape.setSelected(true, (Graphics2D)getGraphics());
    }
    return shapeCheck;
}       


private void setInitialPoint(int x, int y) {
    this.selectedShape = this.shapeTool.clone();
    this.selectedShape.setInitialPoint(x, y);
}



private void setFinalPoint(int x, int y) {
    for(GShapeTool shapeTool: this.shapes) {
        shapeTool.setSelected(false, (Graphics2D)getGraphics());
    }

    //      Graphics2D graphics2D = (Graphics2D) this.getGraphics();
    //set xor mode;
    //      graphics2D.setXORMode(getBackground());
    this.selectedShape.setFinalPoint(x, y);
    this.selectedShape.setSelected(true, (Graphics2D)getGraphics());
    this.shapes.add(this.selectedShape);
}

private void setIntermediatePoint(int x, int y) {
    this.selectedShape.setIntermediatePoint(x, y);  
}

private void animate(int x, int y) {
    Graphics2D graphics2D = (Graphics2D) this.getGraphics();
    //set xor mode;
    graphics2D.setXORMode(getBackground());
    this.selectedShape.animate(graphics2D, x, y);
}




private class MouseHandler 
implements MouseListener, MouseMotionListener, MouseWheelListener {

    private boolean isDrawing;
    MouseHandler() {
        this.isDrawing = false;
    }

    @Override
    public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {

        if(e.getButton() == MouseEvent.BUTTON1) {
            if(e.getClickCount() == 1) {
                this.mouseLButton1Clicked(e);
            } else if(e.getClickCount() == 2) {
                this.mouseLButton2Clicked(e);
            }   
        } else if(e.getButton() == MouseEvent.BUTTON2) {
            if(e.getClickCount() == 1) {
                this.mouseRButton1Clicked(e);
            }
        }
    }



    @Override
    public void mouseMoved(MouseEvent e) {  
        if(isDrawing) {
            if(shapeTool.getDrawingStyle() == EDrawingStyle.eNPointDrawing) {
                animate(e.getX(), e.getY());
            }
        }
    }

    private void mouseLButton1Clicked(MouseEvent e) {
        if(!this.isDrawing) { 
            if(!onShape(e.getX(), e.getY())) {
                if(shapeTool.getDrawingStyle() == EDrawingStyle.eNPointDrawing) {
                    setInitialPoint(e.getX(), e.getY());
                    this.isDrawing = true;
                }
            }
            else if(onShape(e.getX(), e.getY())) {
                onShape(e.getX(), e.getY());
            }

        } else {
            if(shapeTool.getDrawingStyle() == EDrawingStyle.eNPointDrawing) {
                setIntermediatePoint(e.getX(),e.getY());
            }
        }   
    }

    private void mouseLButton2Clicked(MouseEvent e) {
        if(this.isDrawing) {
            if(shapeTool.getDrawingStyle() == EDrawingStyle.eNPointDrawing) {
                setFinalPoint(e.getX(), e.getY());
                this.isDrawing = false;
            }
        }
    }

    private void mouseRButton1Clicked(MouseEvent e) {

    }

    @Override
    public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
        if(e.getButton() == MouseEvent.BUTTON1) {
            if(!this.isDrawing) {
                if(shapeTool.getDrawingStyle() == EDrawingStyle.e2PointDrawing) {
                    setInitialPoint(e.getX(), e.getY());
                    this.isDrawing = true;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    @Override
    public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent e) {
        if(this.isDrawing) {
            if(shapeTool.getDrawingStyle() == EDrawingStyle.e2PointDrawing) {
                animate(e.getX(), e.getY());
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {
        if(this.isDrawing) {
            if(shapeTool.getDrawingStyle() == EDrawingStyle.e2PointDrawing) {
                setFinalPoint(e.getX(), e.getY());
                this.isDrawing = false;
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) {}
    @Override
    public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e) {}        
    @Override
    public void mouseWheelMoved(MouseWheelEvent e) {}

    }
}
```

---

**this is abstract class for shapes**

```
package shapeTool;

import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.Point;
import java.awt.Rectangle;
import java.awt.Shape;
import java.awt.geom.Ellipse2D;
import java.awt.geom.Ellipse2D.Double;
import java.awt.geom.Rectangle2D;
import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.Vector;

import main.GConstants.EAnchorLocation;
import main.GConstants.EDrawingStyle;

public abstract class GShapeTool implements Serializable {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
public enum EAnchors {
    x0y0,
    x0y1,
    x0y2,
    x1y0,
    x1y2,
    x2y0,
    x2y1,
    x2y2,
    RR;
}

public final static int wAnchor = 10;
public final static int hAnchor = 10;

private EDrawingStyle eDrawingStyle;

protected boolean isSelected;

protected Shape shape;
private Ellipse2D[] anchors;

public GShapeTool(EDrawingStyle eDrawingStyle) {
    this.eDrawingStyle = eDrawingStyle;
    this.isSelected = false;
    this.anchors = new Ellipse2D.Double[EAnchors.values().length];
    for(EAnchors eAnchor: EAnchors.values()) {
        this.anchors[eAnchor.ordinal()] = new Ellipse2D.Double();
    }
}

public EDrawingStyle getDrawingStyle() {
    return this.eDrawingStyle;
}

public boolean contains(int x, int y) {
    return this.shape.contains(x , y);
}

private void drawAnchors(Graphics2D graphics2D) {
    // draw bounding rectangle
    Rectangle rectangle = this.shape.getBounds();
    int x0 = rectangle.x-wAnchor;
    int x1 = rectangle.x + rectangle.width/2;
    int x2 = rectangle.x + rectangle.width;
    int y0 = rectangle.y-hAnchor;
    int y1 = rectangle.y + rectangle.height/2;
    int y2 = rectangle.y + rectangle.height;

    this.anchors[EAnchors.x0y0.ordinal()].setFrame(x0,y0,wAnchor,hAnchor);
    this.anchors[EAnchors.x0y1.ordinal()].setFrame(x0,y1,wAnchor,hAnchor);
    this.anchors[EAnchors.x0y2.ordinal()].setFrame(x0,y2,wAnchor,hAnchor);
    this.anchors[EAnchors.x1y0.ordinal()].setFrame(x1,y0,wAnchor,hAnchor);
    this.anchors[EAnchors.x1y2.ordinal()].setFrame(x1,y2,wAnchor,hAnchor);
    this.anchors[EAnchors.x2y0.ordinal()].setFrame(x2,y0,wAnchor,hAnchor);
    this.anchors[EAnchors.x2y1.ordinal()].setFrame(x2,y1,wAnchor,hAnchor);
    this.anchors[EAnchors.x2y2.ordinal()].setFrame(x2,y2,wAnchor,hAnchor);
    this.anchors[EAnchors.RR.ordinal()].setFrame(x1,y0-50,wAnchor,hAnchor);
    //draw anchors
    graphics2D.setColor(Color.BLACK);
    for(EAnchors eAnchor: EAnchors.values()) {
        graphics2D.draw(this.anchors[eAnchor.ordinal()]);
    }
}

private void eraseAnchors(Graphics2D graphics2D) {
    graphics2D.setColor(Color.WHITE);
    for(EAnchors eAnchor: EAnchors.values()) {
        graphics2D.draw(this.anchors[eAnchor.ordinal()]);
    }       
}

public void setSelected(boolean isSelected, Graphics2D graphics2D) {
    if(this.isSelected) {
        if(!isSelected) {
            //erase
            this.eraseAnchors(graphics2D);
        }

    } else {
        if(isSelected) {
            //draw
            this.drawAnchors(graphics2D);
        }

    }
    this.isSelected = isSelected;
}

public void draw(Graphics2D graphics) {
    graphics.draw(this.shape);  
}

public void animate(Graphics2D graphics2d, int x, int y) {
    //erase;
    this.draw(graphics2d);
    //      //move point
    this.movePoint(x,y);
    //      //draw;
    this.draw(graphics2d);
}

//interface
public abstract GShapeTool clone();

public abstract void setInitialPoint(int x, int y);

public abstract void setFinalPoint(int x, int y);

public abstract void setIntermediatePoint(int x, int y);

public abstract void movePoint(int x, int y);
}
```

---

**and this is shape class that extends GShapeTool**

```
package shapeTool;

import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.Rectangle;

import main.GConstants.EDrawingStyle;

public class GRectangle extends GShapeTool {
//attributes
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
//components
//constructor
public GRectangle() {
    super(EDrawingStyle.e2PointDrawing);
    this.shape = new Rectangle();
}

@Override
public GShapeTool clone() {
    GShapeTool cloned = new GRectangle();
    return cloned;
}
// methods
@Override
public void setInitialPoint(int x, int y) {
    Rectangle rectangle = (Rectangle) this.shape;
    rectangle.setLocation(x, y);
    rectangle.setSize(0, 0);
}

@Override
public void setIntermediatePoint(int x, int y) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    
}

@Override
public void setFinalPoint(int x, int y) {
}

@Override
public void movePoint(int x, int y) {
    Rectangle rectangle = (Rectangle) this.shape;
    rectangle.setSize(x-rectangle.x, y-rectangle.y);
    }
}
```

---

Comment: See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22594745/drawing-shape-objects-in-java-draggable-resizable-and-can-rotate or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47516457/drag-a-shape-from-right-to-left-in-java-swing for some ideas.

Comment: looked those ideas but I think I can't use it for my graphics. does not fit to mine.. well thank you for your comment :)

Comment: The point is to understand the concepts and modify your code to use those concepts.

Comment: dear camickr, I made progress! haha , but another problem popped out... :(can you check this one please? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67361470/origin-shape-of-moved-shape-is-not-deleted-and-not-adding-to-shape-shape;

Answer (score 0):

You should get a dragstart event. That is when you save the mouse position and the selected object(s).
When you get a dragfinished event, again note the mouse positon and move the objects accordingly. The move might just happen on the screen, but e.g. in case the drop occurred on the trashcan you want to delete them.

Now while the drag is active you might get a number of more dragging events, which you should use to update the screen and give feedback to the user. This would most of the time just be to look at the mouse positon and the selected objects and draw them accordingly.

Comment: yes, i made some move but there is a problem that the origin of moved shape is deleted and not adding to the shape. um,,, its pretty hard to explain. wait a sec, i will post new question and comment that question's url

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67361470/origin-shape-of-moved-shape-is-not-deleted-and-not-adding-to-shape-shape;

Comment: the url that i just gave you is the one that i am struggling with